# Is it possible to be synced with two or more version control systems at a time

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I am using SVN, but sometime SVN server has to be shutdown for some reasons, I want to be my code synced with SVN and GIT alongside. Is it possible to manage a repository for both of these Version Control Systems at a time?

My scenario is I have a SVN repo with lot of code in it, at office and home pc.

Setup GIT repo in Office PC alongside SVN repo, see following steps.

```
path-to-project: git init
path-to-project: git remote add origin abc.git
path-to-project: git add .
path-to-project: git commit -m "Adding complete project."
path-to-project: git push origin master
```

Finally for Office PC I have setup a repo for both SVN and GIT, where I can work and update both VCS with my latest changes.

But in my Home PC what steps should I follow to be linked with both VCS properly? Keep in mind at this time I have complete SVN project synced at home.

Comment: [git svn](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-as-a-Client) is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Subgit](http://www.subgit.com/documentation.html). It installs post-commit-hooks in git and svn repositories and synchronizes repos on commit. Subgit can work both locally (synchronizing git  and svn servers on server) and remotely (synchronizing remote svn repository with local git repository).